# Is it possible to use same table twice in a JPA criteria search

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to find out if the following is possibe, using javax persistance JPA: join the same table twice, using aliases, so that two different values can be returned in the select statement. For the sample SQL below, the two values would be boss.name and employee.name, both stored in the same table in the same column.

```
SELECT staff.id, boss.name, employee.name 
FROM staff, person as 'boss', person as 'employee', 
WHERE
staff.id = boss.staff_id
AND staff.id = employee.staff_id
AND boss.code = 'boss' 
AND employee.code = 'employee'
```

Also, I'd like to do this, if possible, with straight JDK, not Hibernate. Thanks!

Comment: Do you really intend the boss and the employee to have the same staff_id?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but I'm using derived field names here, I'm just using staff.id as a linking field. The important thing is the aliasing, and the composite join (boss.code = 'boss' and employee.code = 'employee').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need 2 relationships to Person entity from Staff, something like:

```
@Entity
public class Staff {
  ...
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "boss_id")
  Person boss;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
  Person employee;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Another developer I'm working with said he thought that looked like a Hibernate based approach. Do you know if that will work with out Hibernate? Thanks!

Comment: That's a JPA approach, and you can use many providers with jpa, incl hibernate